# Did I corrupt my OS?

Tags: command-line, server, home-directory

I typed this command in the terminal while trying to check if I correctly installed LAMP (Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP) equivalent packages in Ubuntu:

```
sudo mv /home testing.html /var/www/html
```

I am new to this, and i wanted to move the testing.html file from home to `/var/www/html` folder and then run the `http://localhost/testing.html` to check if installation is complete.

After that it started displaying that my home directory and my directory under it; named `yashgugale` has been deleted (`yashgugale` had all the system files). Every time i tried to access documents, pictures, etc. under `yashgugale`. Now it even refused to open terminal and I was unable to copy my `yashgugale` folder back into default start directory.

Where did I go wrong and how I can correct this problem?

Comment: I think by recreating a home directory for the user you can.

Comment: You will need a live CD to fix that. But just out of curiosity as I have never had your issue, but does the following work? Press Alt+F2, this will open dash in a way to allow to run a command. Try running `pkexec mv /var/www/html/home /home` in that box. If it works, this would save you lots of time as you won't need to use a live CD anymore.

Comment: I reinstalled Ubuntu from bootable pd, and replaced previous version with new one. As it is there was less data on it, but now I know where I went wrong. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** Before trying anything, try Dan's solution in a comment under your question:

> Press Alt+F2, this will open dash in a way to allow to run a command.
>   Try running pkexec mv /var/www/html/home /home in that box.

---

I suspect you may have moved /home to /var/www/html/home

If that's the case, run the following to reverse the process:

```
sudo mv /var/www/html/home /home
```

Otherwise, if needed you can recreate a home for your user with:

```
sudo mkdir /home/$USER
sudo chown $USER: /home/$USER
```

You should have originally typed something like:

```
sudo mv /path/to/testing.html /var/www/html/
```

Note the trailing slash. /var/www/html is the html directory. /var/www/html/ means inside the html directory. It's not always needed but I prefer it as it gets me in the habit of giving the system unambivalent instructions.

**Note:** You will probably need to do this via a livecd:

As per http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/reset-your-ubuntu-password-easily-from-the-live-cd/?PageSpeed=noscript, boot up your livecd, open a terminal and enter the following:

```
fdisk -l
```

This will show you which hard drive you are using, typically /dev/sda1.
Then type the following, replacing sda1 with whatever your drive is:

```
sudo mkdir /media/sda1
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/sda1
sudo chroot /media/sda1
```

This mounts your hard drive to the livecd and puts you in chroot. You can now do what I said at the beginning of this answer.

```
exit
```

Now reboot your original system and you should be ok.

Comment: He will need a live dvd session to do this ;)

Comment: I don't have a testing environment set up, but would commands run in the Alt+F2 box in this case? (Though I'd presume  `pkexec`would be a better choice over `sudo` so they can enter the password). This would be easier over using a live CD.

Comment: sudo is fine, no? None of the commands above use a graphic environment. You might be on to something. However, since you don't have a testing environment and neither do I, I can't really incorporate this in the answer ;) Good lateral thinking though. Bravo.

Comment: @SimonHoare I agree, this is why I haven't added it as an answer myself as well; With Alt+F2, if you run `sudo`, you won't be able to have a prompt to ask you for the password to actually run the command with root. Instead, with `pkexec`, it will show a GUI prompt for a password. (I'm not suggesting pkexec because the commands use a graphic environment, instead I'm using it because with Alt+F2, you can't see the "command line feedback"; not sure if I'm making any sense lol).

Comment: Will he be able to do that if he can't run a terminal? In other words, what user information does a terminal running bash require to function that pkexec with Alt + F2 bypasses?

Comment: Ok that should work, provided pkexec in requesting the password doesn't require user details in /home, which I can't see why it would.